# IndexedDB: sometimes object store is not found

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, browser-extension

Good day, in my [browser extension](http://intelligent-speaker.com) I report JavaScript errors. And for the last year, sometimes I get this message:

> IDBDatabase: One of the specified object stores was not found.

Or from Firefox:

> The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found. For example, an object store did not exist but was being opened.

Some of my functions that works with IndexedDB log available object stores (through the db.objectStoreNames) and I see that no objects stores are available (empty response).

I tried again and again to understand what the causes of missing object stores. They are created on extension install. And it works for me and for most users. Maybe Chromium remove object stores when there is not enough disk space? What is the best strategy for such case? Try to recreate object stores?

Comment: Some users use tools like CCleaner that delete IndexedDB. You can use chrome.storage.local as a backup or as a main storage in case your data is JSON-ifiable.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, but this browser extension can store hundreds megabytes of blobs with audio.

Comment: You can try HTML5 FileSystem (Chrome-only, nonstandard) or the upcoming Native File System API.